# Add "question continues" to exam

Tags: exam

I am using the exam package and would like to have "question continues..." in the bottom right of every page where a question continues on to the next page.  I don't want it added if the question does not run on to the next page.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[answers, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{AP Calculus Practice Exam A1}{}{Senior 2}
\firstpageheadrule
\runningheader{AP Calculus Practice Exam A1}
{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
{Senior 2}
\footer{}
{\iflastpage{End of exam}{}}
{}

\begin{document}
%\includepdf{frontpage.pdf}
\begin{questions}
        
\question

\lipsum[1-7]

Some text.

And some more

\question
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

In this example "question continues" should only be added at the bottom of page 2, not at the bottom of page 1.

How can I do that?

---

Using Alain Remillard's answer I now can't have page # of ## in the bottom middle of the pages.  This MWE does not show the page numbers.

```
\documentclass[answers, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\rfoot{page \thepage{} of \numpages}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\footer{}
{\iflastpage{End of exam}{}}
{\ifincomplete{Question continues...}{}}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{headandfoot}}]{frontpage.pdf}
    \begin{questions}
        
        \question
        
        \lipsum[1-10]
        
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the second part, you defined the right footer twice. The second definition cancel the first one. I'll update my answer to add this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at section 11.9 of the [examdoc](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epsh/exam/examdoc.pdf). The `exam` class provides a command named `\ifincomplete{true}{false}`. It works like the `iflastpage` command.

You footer could become

```
\footer{}
{\iflastpage{End of exam}{}}
{\ifincomplete{question confinues}{}}
```

If you need, it also defines the `\IncompleteQuestion` that expands to the number of the current question. The bottom of your page 2 will be "question 2 continues".

**Edit** to take into account the second part of the question.

If you want the page numbers on the other page, use the `false` part of the command. Use this as a footer

```
\footer{}
{\iflastpage{End of exam}{}}
{\ifincomplete{question confinues}{page \thepage{} of \numpages}}
```

If the question continues on the next page, your right footer will be "Question continues". If not, the right footer will be "page # of ##"

Comment: I have updated the question with a problem this solution has caused me.